# bootstrap 3 accordion not collapsing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

For some reason my accordion stopped collapsing on me. I can open the first tab and then open the second tab and that will close the first tab correctly but opening the first tab again or any other tabs and the collapsing stops working.  It was working great when I started. All i have been adding is content to the panel-body and panel heading, I never changed code in the accordion frame and then it just stopped working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Copy of My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/SakuyasLove/sgLxcL75/

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <!-- Accordion 1 START-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">          <h2>STANDARD PIZZA - THIN CRUST - HAND TOSSED</h2>        </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont"><p style="text-align: center;">PIZZARONI TOPPINGS</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont"><p style="text-align: center;"><sup>PEPPERONI - BACON - HAM - SAUSAGE - GROUND BEEF - ONIONS - RED ONIONS - MUSHROOMS - GREEN PEPPER - BLACK OLIVES - GREEN OLIVES - BANANA PEPPERS - JALAPENO PEPPER - PINEAPPLE - TOMATOES - SPINACH - ANCHOVIES - EXTRA CHEESE</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont"><p style="text-align: center;">PREMIUM TOPPINGS</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont"><p style="text-align: center;"><sup>OLD STYLE PEPPERONI - STEAK - CHICKEN - SPICY - COINED SAUSAGE - FETA CHEESE<br><br>
EXTRA TOPPING + $1 EACH<br>
PREMIUM TOPPING + $2 EACH</sup><br><br></p></div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 at-cont"><p style="text-align: right;">SMALL 10î (6 SLICES)</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 at-cont"><p style="text-align: left;">4.99</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 at-cont"><p style="text-align: right;">MEDIUM 12î (8 SLICES)</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 at-cont"><p style="text-align: left;">6.99</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 at-cont"><p style="text-align: right;">LARGE 14î (10 SLICES)</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 at-cont"><p style="text-align: left;">8.99</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 at-cont"><p style="text-align: right;">SMALL 18î (12 SLICES)</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 at-cont"><p style="text-align: left;">12.99<br></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont"><p style="text-align: center;"><br>PREMIUM TOPPINGS</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont"><p style="text-align: center;"><sup>CHEESE ONLY<br>
EXTRA TOPPING + $1 EACH<br>
PREMIUM TOPPING + $2 EACH<br></p></div><br><br>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 at-cont"><p style="text-align: right;">LARGE 14î (10 SLICES)</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 at-cont"><p style="text-align: left;">8.99</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 at-cont"><p style="text-align: right;">X-LARGE 18î (12 SLICES)</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 at-cont"><p style="text-align: left;">12.99</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 1 END-->
<!-- Accordion 2 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2"><h2>SPECIALTY PIZZA</h2></a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
      <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                SMALL 10î (6 SLICES)<br>8.99
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                MEDIUM 12î (8 SLICES)<br>10.99
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                LARGE 14î (10 SLICES)<br>13.99
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                X-LARGE 18î (12 SLICES)<br>19.99
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>1. VEGGIE<br><sup>Green Peppers, Onions, Black Olives, Banana Peppers, Mushrooms</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>2. HAWAIIAN<br><sup>Ham, Bacon, Pineapple, Extra Cheese</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>3. GRILLED CHICKEN<br><sup>Grilled Chicken, Onion, Mushrooms, Banana Peppers</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>4. CHICKEN BACON RANCH<br><sup>Chicken, Bacon &amp; Ranch, (No Pizza Sauce)</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>5. BBQ CHICKEN<br><sup>BBQ Chicken, Red Onion, Bacon (Famous BBQ Sauce)</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>6. BLT<br><sup>Bacon, Lettuce, Tomoto, Mayo, &amp; Extra Cheese (No Pizza Sauce)</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>7. SUPREME<br><sup>Pepperoni, Ham, Bacon, Onions, Green Peppers, Mushrooms</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>8. ALL MEAT<br><sup>Pepperoni, Ham, Hamburger, Bacon, &amp; Ground Beef</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>9. SPICY HAWAIIAN<br><sup>Ham, Bacon, Spicy Coined Sausage, Pineapples, Jalepenos, Extra Cheese</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>10. PIZZARONI EXTRA EVERYTHING<br><sup>Pepperoni, Ham, Bacon, Italian Sausage, Ground Beef, Mushroom, Green Peppers, Onions, Black Olives, Banana Peppers, Pineapples</sup></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 2 END-->
<!-- Accordion 3 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse3">          <h2>CUSTOM 1/2 ANGUS BEEF BURGERS</h2>        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>THE MASTER<br><sup> Sauteed Onions, Mushroom, Jalapenos, American Cheese, Mayo, Mustard
Lettuce, Tomato, Pickles</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>6.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>2.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>HUNGER BUSTER<br><sup> Sauteed Onions, Mushroom, Jalapenos, Bell Pepper, American &amp; Provalone
Cheese, Mayo, Ketchup, Hickory Sauce, Mustard, Lettuce, Bacon, Pickles</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>7.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>3.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>THE WORKS<br><sup> Double Meat (1 lb.), Double American Cheese, Mayo, Lettuce, Tomatoe,
Pickles, Onions</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>7.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>4.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>BACON EGG CHEESEBURGER<br><sup> Bacon, Egg, American Cheese, Swiss Cheese</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>7.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>5.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>AVOCADO CHEESEBURGER<br><sup> Fresh Sliced Avacado, Amercian &amp; Swiss Cheese, Mayo, Lettuce,
Tomato, Onions &amp; Pickles</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>6.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>6.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>GUOCOMOLE CHEESEBURGER<br><sup> Loaded with Guacomole, American Cheese, Mayo, Lettuce, Tomato, Onion
Pickles, Provalone Cheese</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>6.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>7.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>MUSHROOM CHEESEBURGER<br><sup> Sauteed Mushroom, Provalone Cheese, Mayo, Lettuce, Tomato, Onion, Pickles</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>6.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>8.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>TEXAS BACON BLEU CHEESEBURGER<br><sup> Bleu Cheese Crumble, Bacon, Lettuce, Tomtato, Pickles, Onions, Mayo</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>7.99</p></div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 3 END-->
<!-- Accordion 4 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading4">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse4">          <h2>PIZZARONI SIZZLING HOT WINGS</h2>        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading4">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>HAPPY WINGS</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>6 PC.<br>5.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>10 PC.<br>8.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>20 PC.<br>15.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>30 PC.<br>22.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>50 PC.<br>35.99</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>BONELESS WINGS</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1/2 LB.<br>5.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1 LB.<br>9.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>2 LB.<br>18.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>3 LB.<br>22.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>4 LB.<br>35.99</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>JUMBO WHOLE WINGS</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>6 PC.<br>5.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>10 PC.<br>8.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>20 PC.<br>15.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>30 PC.<br>22.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>50 PC.<br>35.99</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>CHICKEN TENDERS</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1/2 LB.<br>5.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1 LB.<br>10.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>2 LB.<br>19.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>3 LB.<br>29.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>4 LB.<br>37.99</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 4 END-->
<!-- Accordion 5 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading5">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse5">          <h2>BARBEQUE DINNER</h2>        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading5">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
            <p style="text-align: center;">Barbecue Dinners Served with Fries, Slaw &amp; Garlic Toast</p>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>RIB TIPS ONLY<br><sup> 1 lb. of Meaty Tender Tips</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>7.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>2.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>RIB TIPS DINNER<br><sup> 1 lb. of Meaty Tender Tips</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>9.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>3.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>RIB TIP BUCKET DINNER<br><sup> 3 lbs. of Meaty Tender Tips</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>23.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>4.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>RIB SMACK DINNER<br><sup> 3-4 Bones of St. Louis BBQ Ribs</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>9.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>5.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>HALF SLAB ONLY<br><sup> 6-7 Bones of St. Louis BBQ Ribs</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>10.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>6.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>HALF SLAB DINNER<br><sup> 6-7 Bones of St. Louis BBQ Ribs</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>12.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>7.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>WHOLE SLAB ONLY<br><sup> 12-13 Bones of St. Louis BBQ Ribs</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>17.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>8.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>WHOLE SLAB DINNER<br><sup> 12-13 Bones of St. Louis BBQ Ribs</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>21.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>9.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>4 PC. HOT LINKS DINNER<br><sup> Spicy Sausage Links Smothered in Our Famous Barbecue Sauce</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>9.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>10.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>HALF BBQ CHICKEN DINNER<br><sup> Smothered in Our Famous Barbecue Sauce</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>9.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>11.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>WHOLE CHICKEN BBQ DINNER<br><sup> Smothered in Our Famous Barbecue Sauce</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>16.99</p></div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 5 END-->
<!-- Accordion 6 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading6">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse6">          <h2>FRIED CHICKEN</h2>        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading6">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;"><p>8 PC. MIXED FRIED CHICKEN - 13.99<br><sup>2 Breasts, 3 Wings, 2 Thighs, 2 Drumsticks</sup></p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;"><p>12 PC. MIXED FRIED CHICKEN DINNER - 17.99<br><sup>3 Breasts, 3 Wings, 3 Thighs, 3 Drumsticks<br></sup></p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;"><p><br>ADD LARGE FRIES, 2 SLAW &amp; GARLIC TOAST FOR $3.99</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 6 END-->
<!-- Accordion 7 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading7">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse7">          <h2>CHICKEN DINNER</h2>        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading7">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;"><p>2 PC. FRIED CHICKEN DINNER - $5.99<br><sup>2 Breasts, 3 Wings, 2 Thighs, 2 Drumsticks</sup></p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 at-cont" style="text-align: center;"><p>4 PC. FRIED CHICKEN DINNER - $8.99<br><sup>3 Breasts, 3 Wings, 3 Thighs, 3 Drumsticks<br></sup></p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;"><p><br>ADD LARGE FRIES, 2 SLAW &amp; GARLIC TOAST FOR $3.99</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 7 END-->
<!-- Accordion 8 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading8">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse8" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse8">          <h2>CIABATTAS &amp; SUBS</h2>        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading8">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p style="text-align: center;">All Ciabattas or Subs Are Oven Toasted &amp; Served with Fries</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>VEGGIE<br><sup> Lettuce, Tomato, Red Onions, Banana Peppers, Black Olives,
Mozzerella Cheese, American Cheese, Dressing</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>7.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>2.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>HAM &amp; CHEESE<br><sup> Grilled Ham, Cheese, Lettuce, Tomato, Cheese, Banana Peppers,
Red Onions, Mayo, Italian Dressing</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>9.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>3.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>TURKEY &amp; CHEESE<br><sup> Turkey, Cheese, Lettuce, Banana Peppers, Red Onions, Mayo,
Italian Dressing</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>23.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>4.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>ITALIAN<br><sup> Ham, Salami, Pepperoni, Cheese, Lettuce, Tomato, Red Onions,
Mayo, Italian Dressing</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>9.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>5.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>CLUB<br><sup> Turkey, Ham, Bacon, Cheese, Lettuce, Tomto, Banana Peppers,
Red Onions, Mayo & Dressing</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>12.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>6.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>STEAK &amp; CHEESE<br><sup> Grilled Steak, Cheese, Lettuce, Onion, Banana Peppers, Mayo,
Italian Dressing</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>17.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>7.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>PHILLY CHEESESTEAK<br><sup> Grilled Stak, Melted Cheddar, Cheese, White Onions, Green Peppers,
Mushroom, Banana Peppers</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>21.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>8.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>GRILLED CHICKEN<br><sup> Grilled Chicken, Cheese, Lettuce, Tomato, Banana Pepper,
Red Onions, Mayo, Italian Dressing  </sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>9.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>9.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>CHICKEN BACON RANCH<br><sup> Grilled Chicken, Bacon, Cheese, Lettuce, Tomato, Ranch Dressing</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>9.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>10.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>PIZZA<br><sup> Pepperoni, Ham, Bacon, White Onions, Mushrooms, Green Peppers,
Extra Cheese, Pizza Sauce</sup></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>10.99</p></div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 8 END-->
<!-- Accordion 9 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading9">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse9" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse9">          <h2>SALADS</h2>        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading9">
  <div class="panel-body">
 <p style="text-align: center;">Available Dressings:<br>
Gourmet Italian, Ranch, Greek, French, Blue Cheese, Light Raspberry Vinagrette</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p></p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont"><p></p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>SMALL</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>LARGE</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1.</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont"><p>TOSSED SALAD<br><sup>Fresh Crisp Lettuce, Topped with Tomotoes, Onions,
Pepperoncini Pepper, Cheese, Croutons</sup></p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>4.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>7.99</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>2.</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont"><p>ANTIPASTO SALAD<br><sup>Fresh Crisp Lettuce, Topped with Ham, Salami, Cheese, Onions,
Pepperoncini Pepper, Black Olives, Croutons</sup></p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>8.99</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>3.</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont"><p>GREEK SALAD<br><sup>Fresh Crisp Lettuce, Topped with Tomatoes, Onions, Feta Cheese,
Sliced Beets, Pepperoncini Pepper, Black Olives</sup></p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>8.99</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>4.</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont"><p>GRILLED CHICKEN SALAD<br><sup>Fresh Crisp Lettuce, Topped with Grilled Chicken, Tomotoes, Onions,
Pepperoncini Pepper, Croutons</sup></p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>8.99</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>5.</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 at-cont"><p>PIZZARONI SALAD<br><sup>Fresh Crisp Lettuce, Topped with Chicken Tenders, Tomatoes, Onions,
Pepperoncini Pepper, Shredded Cheddar, Cheese, Croutons</sup></p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>8.99</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 9 END-->
<!-- Accordion 10 START-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading10">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse10" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse10">          <h2>PIZZARONI KID ZONE</h2>        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse10" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading10">
  <div class="panel-body">
        <p style="text-align: center;">10 &amp; Under (Served with Small Fries &amp; Drink)</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>1.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>PIZZARONI KID PIZZA</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>2.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>CHICKEN STRIPS</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>3.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>CHICKEN NUGGETS</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>4.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>JR. CHEESE BURGER</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>5.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>CORNY DOG BITS</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>6.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>THE BBQ PLATE</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-num"><p>7.</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 at-cont"><p>SLIDDERS</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 at-price"><p>5.99</p></div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion 10 END-->
</div>
```

MORE ACCORDIANS IN JSFIDDLE LINK

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what the issue is? When i click on a tab it opens, i click again it closes.
If the tabs are ordered like this:

1

2

3

and i open 1, then open 2: 1 closes and 2 opens.
If i open 2, then open 1: they both stay open.

That seems to be a desired behavior.

Comment: go further down. I said in my post that the 1st 2 seemed to work, the rest dont work

Comment: For instance this is how it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/SakuyasLove/95e1j1fg/